# Ironpython and future statements

Tags: silverlight, ironpython, dynamic-language-runtime

I am using IronPython as a math parser with the DLR in my Silverlight project: it works, but computes incorrect results in cases involving division, as it uses integer instead of floating point math at times (so 4/3 returns 1). Google suggests adding `from __future__ import division` to the python script, but doing so throws an exception when I try to run it.

Are `__future__` statements supported at all in IronPython? What can I do to make them work?

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to make sure that `__future__.py` is available for import. I'm not sure how to do that for Silverlight, though.

Comment: Just add the `__future__.py` file next to your other python files in Silverlight app folder.

Answer (score 1):

Besides what Jeff suggested, you can also set the division behaviour when setting up the engine

```
var engineOptions = new Dictionary<string, object>();
engineOptions["DivisionOptions"] = PythonDivisionOptions.New;
var engine = Python.CreateEngine(engineOptions);
Console.WriteLine("{0}", engine.Execute("4 / 3"));
```

or when you compile your script:

```
var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
var compilerOptions = (PythonCompilerOptions)engine.GetCompilerOptions();
compilerOptions.Module |= ModuleOptions.TrueDivision;
var code = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString("4 / 3").Compile(compilerOptions);
Console.WriteLine("{0}", code.Execute());
```

Comment: Great, the first method is just what I needed instead of bothering with setting the search path, which is kind of tricky in a server environment. Thank you!